# css hover em uma tabela com rowspan

Tags: html, css

**Tabela - Exemplo**

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

tr:hover {
  background-color:coral;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Col 1</th>
    <th>Col 2</th>
    <th>Col 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Dados1</td>
    <td>Dados1</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Dados1 Rowspan</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Dados1</td>
    <td>Dados1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Dados2</td>
    <td>Dados2</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Dados2 Rowspan</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Dados2</td>
    <td>Dados2</td>
  </tr>



</table>
```

Como posso utilizar o efeito [hover](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp) para mudar a cor da linha completa como na imagem abaixo ?

**Exemplo** :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual o problema, ao que parece o `hover `está funcionado?

Comment: Por exemplo quando o usuário passar o mouse todas as informações dos dados ficariam com mesmo background , ou seja na linha inteira e não pegando somente algumas linhas.

Comment: cara tá confuso isso, o que você quer é que apenas as  `td` (Table Data) contendo o atributo `rowspan` que recebem o `hover` troquem o background? Isso for isso a resposta abaixo , resolve... Se não for isso procure dar o nome correto aos elementos que queres manipular se não fica confuso.

Comment: Você quer que ao passar o mouse por cima de um item da linha toda a linha altere o background ou cada item da tabela separado?

Comment: me desculpem realmente estava bem confuso kk , já editei o enunciado..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando Jquery:

- Acrescente em suas `<tr>` uma mesma classe que represente a linha do conteúdo.

Feito isso o Jquery irá capturar o evento de passar o mouse por cima da `<tr>` após isso irá obter a classe da mesma e atribuir o `background-color` para todas as outras `<tr>` que possuem a mesma classe.

```js
$('tr').hover(function(){

  var mudar = $(this).attr('class');
  
  $('.'+mudar).css('background-color','coral');

},function(){

     var mudar = $(this).attr('class');
  
  $('.'+mudar).css('background-color','#fff');

});
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Col 1</th>
    <th>Col 2</th>
    <th>Col 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class='linha1'>
    <td>Dados1</td>
    <td>Dados1</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Dados1 Rowspan</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='linha1'>
    <td>Dados1</td>
    <td>Dados1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class='linha2'>
    <td>Dados2</td>
    <td>Dados2</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Dados2 Rowspan</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='linha2'>
    <td>Dados2</td>
    <td>Dados2</td>
  </tr>



</table>
```